# HTML DOM appendChild script async

Tags: javascript, html

I'm adding some js script like this:

```
  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'https://cdn.some/file.js';
  script.async = true;
  script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
  document.body.appendChild(script);
```

What is the use of `.async = true;` ?

Comment: It means the script is executed asynchronously with the rest of the page (the script will be executed while the page continues the parsing)

Comment: Not sure there is a point - don't dynamically injected scripts run only once the page is parsed anyway?

Comment: hm, si I don't need that they be loaded asynchronously, I won't use "true" then, I wonder what's the default value. Of course I need them to be loaded synchronously, I need them first some other scripts

Comment: @pmiranda Default value should be false.